# Explanation about step in derivation (differential equation with integrating factor)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I see in a textbook about Differential Equations
$\frac{\mu'(t)}{\mu(t)} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Then it says this is equivalent to
$\frac{d}{dt} ln|\mu(t)| = \frac{1}{2}$. I am not understanding this step completely, could somebody explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @Derk It's (supposed to be) an equivalence. Which direction are you having trouble with? The truth is it isn't equivalent. The *only if* direction is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g (t)=\ln\mu(t)$ then $g'(t)=\frac {\mu'(t)}{\mu(t)}$

So here we are using derivative of composite functions rule:

If $f(t)=p(r(t))$, then $f'(t)=r'(t)p'(r(t))$

Now in our case, $r(t)=\mu(t),p(t)=\ln(t)$, Here we see that $p'(t)=(\ln(t))'=\frac{1}{t}$

Thus $p(\mu(t))'=\mu'(t)p'(\mu(t))=\frac{\mu'(t)}{\mu(t)}$

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks! completely clear now